# Using WinPCap for UDP receiving

Tags: udp, winpcap

I would like to use WinPCap library for "reliable" UDP receiving in my C++ application. All examples that I found, using this library for capturing  and then proceding. Is there any way (example) how to configure PCap for streaming mode and receive UDP only and on uder defined port or how to solve this. In this time I have reliable UDP server able to receiving 0.5Gb/s. But on slower PC I have a packet lose I can see packets in ethereal but not in application.

thanks

vsm

Comment: Why? It's much simpler using the Sockets API, and WinPCap doesn't make it any more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already tried all of the more standard methods of increasing the number of datagrams that you are able to process? Things like increasing the recv buffer size, speeding up the processing that you do per datagram and using IOCP to allow you to bring more threads to bear on the problem or using RIO if you can target Windows 8?

If so then using WinPCap might work but it sounds like a bit of an extreme solution.

What you need to do is create a filter so that you only capture the datagrams that you are interested in... The docs include examples which use filters.

Comment: I have IOCP UDP server from: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/533159-article-using-udp-with-iocp/.

Answer (score 0):

I have server from here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/533159-article-using-udp-with-iocp/. This code working with IOCP. Its working fine on WIndows XP. There is no problem with receiving 0.5Gb/s. But now on Win7 is little unreliable. Sometimes there are packets positions error. (my device generating udp packets and in its payload there is PacketNumber - number increasing with each packet. When error occured i write all packet numbers into file. I can see for exmaple: 10,11,290,13,14... ). Is there any known differences in WinXP and Win7 for IOCP and multi threading? Or do you konw any free UDP server with IOCP processing?

In procedding loop I only adding packets into buffer and checking their numbers.